# can you bypass the login to a asp.net site using only a unique url?

Tags: asp.net, url, authentication

I'm just curious if you can bypass the login into a asp.net website, which to let yall know, I have no control of using a unique url?

I have login credentials to the site, and tried using those to do this but to no avail.

So is this possible? Only thing I could think of was

```
http://username:password.awesomesauce.com/login/login.aspx
```

FYI I can log in fine, I just need this to login to the site via a 3rd party app. It is a major pain to login everytime with the app and sometimes many of the functions fail because its screwy with keeping an authenticated login

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used a firefox add on called *Live HTTP Headers 0.17* to follow the url actions as it logins into the site. After turning on the capture option I logged in and it gave me this

[image: le image]

Then I took the contents from the Content-Length catagory and appended it to the url like so

`https://www.TROLLFACE.com/login/login.aspx?__LASTFOCUS=&__EVENTTARGET=&__EVENTARGUMENT=&__VIEWSTATE=%2FwEPDwUJMTI2OTI3NTE1D2QWAmYPZBYCAgMPZBYMAiAPDxYCHgdWaXNpYmxlaGRkAiEPDxYCHwBoZGQCJg8WAh4LXyFJdGVtQ291bnQCGhYCAhkPZBYCAgEPFgIeBXN0eWxlBQtib3JkZXI6MHB4O2QCKA8WAh8AaGQCKg8PFgIeC05hdmlnYXRlVXJsBRZqYXZhc2NyaXB0Om9wZW5DaGF0KCk7ZGQCOQ8PFgIeBFRleHQFKUNvcHlyaWdodCAmY29weTsgMjAxMiBCIE8gWCBQYXJ0bmVycywgTExDZGQYAQUeX19Db250cm9sc1JlcXVpcmVQb3N0QmFja0tleV9fFgEFGGN0bDAwJGJ0bkNoZWNrSW52ZW50b3J5MdYH4EkMQWCgv%2FEOSMLJPNZ21rMa&ctl00%24cphMain%24txtUsername=USERNAME-GOES-HERE&ctl00%24cphMain%24txtPassword=PASSWORD-GOES-HERE8&ctl00%24cphMain%24btnLogin=Log+In`

Please note the **USERNAME-GOES-HERE** and the **PASSWORD-GOES-HERE**

So far it works every single time, effectively skipping the login.

Answer (score 1):

No, this is not normally possible.

This would be a very specific custom case - there is no standard for this as all logins are different, and authentication methods with databases etc. are all different.

FTP can work like this, but that is because the authentication is part of the protocol whereas in a web form it is not.

Comment: ok thank you for the quick answer! I guess I will have to find a work around

Comment: hmm, I'm not sure if we have any permissions on the FTP side but it would be awesome if we did!